# Trigger Not Executing Yet It's Created

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have a trigger function I'm trying to have execute in Postgres.

It compiles and adds the trigger, however it does not insert the value into the table as I had hoped.

The function it uses looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
calc_gnpDifference(n integer, o integer)
RETURNS NUMERIC AS $$
        SELECT $1 ::numeric - $2::numeric AS gnpDifference;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And the Trigger part:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION autoCalculate() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
        BEGIN

        IF NEW.gnp_old > NEW.gnp_old THEN
                NEW.gnpDifference := calc_gnpDifference(NEW.gnp_old, NEW.gnp);
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;
        END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER insertDifference ON country;
CREATE TRIGGER insertDifference BEFORE INSERT ON country
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE autoCalculate();
```

However, when I insert data, the trigger does not update the gnpDifference field as I had hoped. Thoughts on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 5):

Obviously this condition: `IF NEW.gnp_old > NEW.gnp_old` will never be true so the trigger will never have any effect.